# error when using Amadeus get started guide for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, amadeus

I am new to Amadeus and am currently stuck at the first step. I am using the test URL (test.api.amadeus.com) When I use the example code with my API key and API secret, I get the following:

```
ClientError
```

Below is the backend code I used with the key and secret:

```js
const express = require('express');
const Amadeus = require('amadeus');

const app = express();
const amadeus = new Amadeus({
    clientId: '{API key}',
    clientSecret: '{API secret}'
});

amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get({
    originLocationCode: 'SYD',
    destinationLocationCode: 'BKK',
    departureDate: '2022-06-01',
    adults: '2'
}).then(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(responseError){
  console.log(responseError.code);
});


app.use(express.static('client'));

app.listen(8080);
```

No issues on the express side.

I can get my access token using the curl command on the "get started" guide, however when I run the below curl command I get this error:

command:

```
curl -X GET 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=PAR&maxPrice=200' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{token}}'
```

response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 38190,
            "title": "Invalid access token",
            "detail": "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid",
            "status": 401
         }
     ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. I can't seem to see where I have gone wrong

Comment: Hello, it seems like your API key and secret are outdated or wrong. from the first curl command that you get access token, did you get correctly? can you also check again if you replaced {{token}} with your actually token that you received?

Comment: I am adding the amadeus for developers documentation page also to make sure we are aligned : https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/API-Keys/authorization/

Answer (score 0):

I used for React may it help for u..

```
const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID
const clientSecret = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET

export const getAmadeusToken = async () => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers()
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

  var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams()
  urlencoded.append("client_id", clientId)
  urlencoded.append("client_secret", clientSecret)
  urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials")

  var requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: urlencoded,
    redirect: "follow",
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
      requestOptions
    )
    let token = await response.json()
    //console.log(token.access_token)

    return token.access_token
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```